# file location identification in informatica

Tags: unix, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have few file names and need to identify which mapping/workflow is generating those files? Is it possible to check this in repository or at UNIX level. your advise may help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the PowerCenter repository database, you can get information about file connections associated with sessions (e.g. source or target files) from the **Metadata Exchange (MX) views**:

- `REP_SESSION_FILES` contains file connections associated with reusable sessions
  [image: REP_SESSION_FILES]
- `REP_SESSION_INST_FILES` contains file connection information for session instances associated with workflows
  [image: REP_SESSION_INST_FILES]

Source: [PowerCenter 8.6.1. Repository Guide](https://mysupport.informatica.com/docs/DOC-1679) (login required)

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon how you have named your objects, it may be possible to identify those files against particular mappings.

For example, Informatica will generate several `Cache` files in Cache directory. If you are using cached `Lookup`, depending upon the names of the lookup (or the name that you have used in `named cache`) you may identify which lookup has created that file. This approach is also applicable with `Aggregator` cache or `Rank` cache.

It would be easier if you can maintain a offline mapping between the transformations names and which mapping contains those transformations

Answer (score 0):

Informatica Support team has come up with a tool called 'Metaquery' which could be used to get Metadata Information. This tool might give you the details you are looking for. This could be downloaded from Informatica Marketplace or their support site.